# Getting a rating for a song with Apple Music API

Tags: ios, swift, apple-music

I am trying to get the rating for a song via the Apple Music API, as it describes [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/get_a_personal_song_rating).

Hence, the URL I am using is:

```
https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/ratings/songs/493341471
```

493341471 is the playbackStoreID (of the MPMediaItem) of the song 'Born to Die'. I have this song in my library, and I have added it to my "loved" list both on iTunes on my computer and on my iPhone. Yet, when I make this GET request, I get back a 404 Resource not Found error from Apple.

I also tried the same url but using the MPMediaItem property persistentId (its persistentID is 2932020188133715832), and that didn't work either.

The documentation says the url format is

```
https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/ratings/songs/{id}
```

and their example gives a 9 digit id, exactly as the playbackStoreID I used above.

I tried searching the Apple Music [catalogue](https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/search?term=borrn+to+die&types=songs) for this song, and the id that was returned was indeed 493341471.

Yet, no matter what I do, I get a resource not found. Anyone have any idea what "id" the documentation here may be referring to?

Comment: The api description mentions that the endpoint requires a music user token, are you including that in the get request?

Comment: yes indeed. I am able to fetch my recommendations and other personalised content.

Comment: other song id's don't have the same problem?

Comment: yes they all do, I've tried 4 others as well. I get Resource not Found 404 for all of them.

Comment: do you also get a 404 if you put a rating to that song id?

Comment: yep indeed I do.

Comment: Maybe this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/get_a_personal_library_song_rating

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to like/dislike a specific song with your apple music account then you can get an HTTP 200 response.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).